# Deleting a Standard TCP IP port using xcvdata not working

Tags: c++, windows

Xcvdata() for deleting port.

```
BOOL DeletePortCus( TCHAR* PortName )
{
    HANDLE hPrinter;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS PrinterDefaults;
    memset(&PrinterDefaults, 0, sizeof(PrinterDefaults));

    PrinterDefaults.pDatatype       = NULL;
    PrinterDefaults.pDevMode        = NULL;
    PrinterDefaults.DesiredAccess   = SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER;

    DWORD needed = 0;
    DWORD rslt = 0;

    //Port data
    PORT_DATA_1 pOutputData ;
    DWORD error = 0;


    if (!OpenPrinter(L",XcvMonitor Standard TCP/IP Port", &hPrinter, &PrinterDefaults))
    {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf; 
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL ); 

        _tprintf( TEXT("Error in OpenPrinter. Error msg : %s"),lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );

        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD xcvresult= 0;

    if (
        !XcvData(
            hPrinter, 
            TEXT("DeletePort"),
            (PBYTE)PortName,
            (lstrlen(PortName) +1) * sizeof(TCHAR), //the 1 is for the trailing NULL
            ( byte * ) &pOutputData,
            sizeof(PORT_DATA_1), 
            &needed, 
            &xcvresult)
        )
    {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf; 

        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL ); 

        _tprintf( TEXT("Error in XcvData. Error msg : %s; XcvDataPort status val = %d"), lpMsgBuf, xcvresult);
        LocalFree( lpMsgBuf );

        return FALSE;
    }

    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    return TRUE;
}
```

The highlight is both the functions (**openprinter** and **xcvdata**) succeed. But the port is not getting removed. I am completely at a loss here as I dont have any error to lookup.

Instead of `,XcvMonitor Standard TCP/IP Port` I also tried with `,XcvPort <portname>`. Still same.
As Samer suggested below, I tried with `OpenPrinter2` with no cache option.

PS: I know there's this simple alternative DeletePort(), but it invokes a UI dialog box if it fails, so I don't want to use it.

Comment: You mention you don't know when it stopped working, maybe go back in OS versions etc. to when it last work or when it starts working again. You can then start trawling through the release notes and changes from the version onwards that may affect your code. You also mention that the functions succeed but the port isn't closed. How do you know it isn't removed?

Comment: Could you try to use `XcvDataPort` without the last parameter `&xcvresult` to see if it gives you the same result?

Comment: @niall there are few ways to identify the printer ports. One way is using printmanagement.msi from run, it lists all available printer ports, printers and drivers,

Comment: @samer I'll try it tomorrow and update here. But what could be the difference between the two? Checked both functions MSDN pages but it does not talk about any difference except for the parameters as far as I can understand.

Comment: Blind shot: do you run this in elevated mode? An admin account?

Comment: @R2RT that wont work, since XcvData would return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, but the call suceeds in this case according to op

Comment: @Shameel Mohamed Its just I am suspcious of the internals. Secondly I think the handle is a cached one. In vista there was a problem with `OpenPrinter`, it cached the printer handles. They introduced another call `OpenPrinter2`. Can you also try `OpenPrinter2` function with the `PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE` flag?.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue might be related to specific version of OS which caches printer handles. To get around this you use an alternate call `OpenPrinter2` with the `PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE`. Below is the modified code with the flag set.

```
HANDLE hPrinter;
PRINTER_DEFAULTS PrinterDefaults;
memset(&PrinterDefaults, 0, sizeof(PrinterDefaults));

PrinterDefaults.pDatatype       = NULL;
PrinterDefaults.pDevMode        = NULL;
PrinterDefaults.DesiredAccess   = SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER;

PRINTER_OPTIONS PrinterOptions;
PrinterOptions.cbSize = sizeof(PrinterOptions);
PrinterOptions.dwFlags = PRINTER_OPTION_NO_CACHE;

DWORD needed = 0;
DWORD rslt = 0;

//Port data
PORT_DATA_1 pOutputData ;
DWORD error = 0;

if (!OpenPrinter2(L",XcvMonitor Standard TCP/IP Port", &hPrinter, &PrinterDefaults, &PrinterOptions))
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
```

Comment: As u suggested I tried using XcvDataPort instead of XcvData, but it seems the function is removed from the native library, coz I get unresolved external symbol error. I have included the winsplp.h. I tried adding winsplp.lib, it is not available. Other functions of winsplp.h are also not resolved.